# React-router TypeError: _NavbarActions2.default.updateOnlineUsers is not a function

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, reactjs, react-router

Im using nodeJs and react 0.14.2 with react-router 1.0.3 and history 1.17.0. When I navigate on my application whatever action I try to execute I get "undefined", as an example fetching a character from database

```
import alt from '../alt';
import {assign} from 'underscore';

class NavbarActions {
 constructor() {
 this.actions = alt.generateActions(
  'updateOnlineUsers',
  'updateAjaxAnimation',
  'updateSearchQuery',
  'getCharacterCountSuccess',
  'getCharacterCountFail',
  'findCharacterSuccess',
  'findCharacterFail'
 );
 this.findCharacter = this.findCharacter.bind(this);
}

findCharacter(payload) {
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/characters/search',
  data: { name: payload.searchQuery }
})
  .done((data) => {
    assign(payload, data);
    self.actions.findCharacterSuccess(payload);
  })
  .fail(() => {
    self.actions.findCharacterFail(payload);
  });
 }

 getCharacterCount() {
  $.ajax({ url: '/api/characters/count' })
  .done((data) => {
    self.actions.getCharacterCountSuccess(data)
  })
  .fail((jqXhr) => {
    self.actions.getCharacterCountFail(jqXhr)
  });
 }
}

export default alt.createActions(NavbarActions);
```

I get an error on debug and can no longer type in the seach bar

```
TypeError: _NavbarActions2.default.updateOnlineUsers is not a function
```

However when I debug I see that I get a json string with my data and payload object is not null and has data.

NavbarActions are called from Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import NavbarStore from '../stores/NavbarStore';
import NavbarActions from '../actions/NavbarActions';

class Navbar extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = NavbarStore.getState();
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
 NavbarStore.listen(this.onChange);
 NavbarActions.getCharacterCount();

 let socket = io.connect();

 socket.on('onlineUsers', (data) => {
   NavbarActions.updateOnlineUsers(data);
 });

 $(document).ajaxStart(() => {
   NavbarActions.updateAjaxAnimation('fadeIn');
 });

 $(document).ajaxComplete(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    NavbarActions.updateAjaxAnimation('fadeOut');
  }, 750);
 });
}
componentWillUnmount() {
 NavbarStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
}

onChange(state) {
 this.setState(state);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();

let searchQuery = this.state.searchQuery.trim();

if (searchQuery) {
  NavbarActions.findCharacter({
    searchQuery: searchQuery,
    searchForm: this.refs.searchForm,
    history: this.props.history
  });
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your generateActions method defined? Can you post some details about that also?

Comment: generationActions is just a shorthand found in this link http://alt.js.org/docs/createActions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by creating a new project folder and re-running a clean npm install. I think I had an issu with my dependencies

Answer (score 0):

There was some basic scope related problem, I hope this should work.

```
    import alt from '../alt';
    import {assign} from 'underscore';

    class NavbarActions {
      constructor() {
       this.generateActions(
       'updateOnlineUsers',
       'updateAjaxAnimation',
       'updateSearchQuery',
       'getCharacterCountSuccess',
       'getCharacterCountFail',
       'findCharacterSuccess',
       'findCharacterFail'
     );
     this.findCharacter = this.findCharacter.bind(this);
    }

    findCharacter(payload) {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/characters/search',
      data: { name: payload.searchQuery }
    })
      .done((data) => {
        assign(payload, data);
        self.actions.findCharacterSuccess(payload);
      })
      .fail(() => {
        self.actions.findCharacterFail(payload);
      });
    }
    export default alt.createActions(NavbarActions);
```

Comment: Tkx but unfortunatly it gives me a different errors on this part of the code '    socket.on('onlineUsers', (data) => {
      NavbarActions.updateOnlineUsers(data);
    });' error : 'TypeError: _NavbarActions2.default.updateOnlineUsers is not a function'